# Matching multiple strings ending with

Tags: python

I'm looking for a more efficient way of matching multiple arbitrary domains from a block of text.

I have a block of text looks like this:

```
'''
    foo
    my.domain1
    batman.my.domain1
    superman.my.domain2 foo bar wonderwoman.my.domain1
'''
```

I want to match all subdomains of
`my.domain1` and 
`my.domain2`

Desired output here would be:

> ['batman.my.domain1', 'superman.my.domain2', 'wonderwoman.my.domain1']

I have accomplished the task partially by using this monster of a regex that surely can't be the most efficient way to do this:

```
r'(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{,}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+my.domain1|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{,}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+my.domain2'
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Example code:

```
import re

text = '''
    foo
    my.domain1
    batman.my.domain1
    superman.my.domain2 foo bar wonderwoman.my.domain1
'''

pattern = r'(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{,}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+my.domain1|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{,}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+my.domain2'
print(re.findall(pattern, text))

# Desired output is:
# ['batman.my.domain1', 'superman.my.domain2', 'wonderwoman.my.domain1']
```

P.S - my.domain1 and my.domain2 are example domains, real ones will not have numbers at the end.

Comment: The code you posted generates the same output as desired - anything wrong?

Comment: If domain1 and domain2 aren't actually domains, what should we actually be matching for?

Comment: You can simplify the regex using `my.domain[12]` instead of repeating the whole thing for domain2.

Comment: if those are just fake data for the example, you can do something like `(firstdomain|second.dom)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`endswith()` comes to an aid. I respect regular expressions, but checking the domain to be a subdomain is so much strictly related to `.endswith()` logic, that I would avoid putting regex's for this purpose. And, btw, regex syntax is in 99% hardly readable comparing to plain strings.

```
accepted_domains = ['my.domain1', 'my.domain2']

text = '''
    foo
    my.domain1
    batman.my.domain1
    superman.my.domain2 foo bar wonderwoman.my.domain1
'''

result = []

for dom in text.lower().split():
    for acc_dom in accepted_domains:
        #if dom == acc_dom or dom.endswith('.' + acc_dom):  # if you want 'my.domain1' to be included
        if dom.endswith('.' + acc_dom):
            result.append(dom)

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['batman.my.domain1', 'superman.my.domain2', 'wonderwoman.my.domain1']
```

Comment: This will work for the example, but may be difficult to generalise.

Answer (score 1):

Two improvements I can provide:

1. Use `\w` for a shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` if you don't care about underscores
2. Use `(?:pattern1|pattern2)` to "generalize" the ending.

```
import re

text = '''
    foo
    my.domain1
    batman.my.domain1
    superman.my.domain2 foo bar wonderwoman.my.domain1
'''

pattern = r'(?:\w+\.)+(?:my\.domain1|my\.domain2)'
print(re.findall(pattern, text))
```

If you want to match hyphens inside domain parts:

```
pattern = r'(?:\w(?:[\w-]?\w)*\.)+(?:my\.domain1|my\.domain2)'
```

This will match `asdf-ghjkl.my.domain1` but not `asdf--ghjkl.my.domain2` (no consecutive hyphens).

For consecutive hyphen sequences:

```
pattern = r'(?:\w(?:[\w-]*\w)?\.)+(?:my\.domain1|my\.domain2)'
```

Answer (score -2):

Operating under the assumption what you really want is a string with two periods in it...

```
>>> text = '''
    ...     foo
    ...     my.domain1
    ...     batman.my.domain1
    ...     superman.my.domain2 foo bar wonderwoman.my.domain1
    ... '''
    >>> data = [x for x in text.split() if x.count('.') ==2 and x.endswith(('2','1'))]
    >>> data
    ['batman.my.domain1', 'superman.my.domain2', 'wonderwoman.my.domain1']
```

Comment: This may return false positives (i.e., links that are not subdomains of OP's example).

Comment: Didn't see the 2 domain requirement, bu it still looks pretty simple.. updated my answer.